# Convert.ToDateTime OR DateTime.ParseExact(string, Format, null)

Tags: c#

i have a problem that i am saving the value in database `DatetimePicker.Value.Day(which returns Int);`
now i am getting this value on another form on

```
label.Text = DataGridViewName.Rows[0].Cells["ColumnName"] +"-"+System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

now i want to compare the value of label.Text with current date ... so i have to convert the label.text into datetime

```
DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Label.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy",null);
```

OR

```
Convert.ToDatetime(label.text);
```

but both conversion gives me error of String is not Valid and geirgian calender ERROR
i cannot understand what to do

Comment: You can convert it by
     DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Label.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvarientCulture);

Comment: i found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851285/how-to-get-datepicker-value-in-date-format) He converts it into string and get the date format

Comment: @Shashank , you should turn your comment as answer :) Take some reputations !

Comment: @Dani Danish: I have added my answer. You can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it by

```
DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Label.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvarientCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = lblDueDate.Text;
                    DateTime DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Here `lblDueDate.Text` has Date which i have stored from database and then i have convert `lblDueDate.Text` in `DateTime` for comparing this Date from Current Date